# Javascript to SWF on separated domains

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash

I have an application with embed swf thatis called from javascript using handleEvent, This was working fine when they were both on same domain but now when i seperated them it returns an error , any ideas ??

Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you be a bit more clear about this ? 'both' = js+swf or you have 2 swfs ? also paste the message from the error. It might be a Security sandbox error

Comment: wait a minute... swf files and js files are both run client-side, right? are you trying to connect two clients?

Comment: or are they being served from two different domains?

Answer (score 1):

Solved :-)
I use allowDomain (myDomain) in the swf file.